# Opencart 2.2.0 Latest page - sorting by two parameters

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I am using OC 2.2.0 and I made custom Latest page where I display 20 latest products. I managed to make the default sorting to be by date added in decsending order. For some reason, I am struggling to make other sorting options(by name, price and model) work properly. The correct number of products is shown (20 in my case), but they are not latest. They are just products from all products list instead. My

> controller file latest.php,looks like this:

```
<?php
class ControllerProductLatest extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('product/latest');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
        } else {
            $sort = 'p.sort_order';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $order = $this->request->get['order'];
        } else {
            $order = 'DESC';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $page = $this->request->get['page'];
        } else {
            $page = 1;
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $limit = (int)$this->request->get['limit'];
        } else {
            $limit = $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_limit');
        }

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
        );

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
        }

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('product/latest', $url)
        );

        $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
        $data['customer_group_id'] = $this->customer->getGroupId();
        $data['text_empty'] = $this->language->get('text_empty');
        $data['text_quantity'] = $this->language->get('text_quantity');
        $data['text_manufacturer'] = $this->language->get('text_manufacturer');
        $data['text_model'] = $this->language->get('text_model');
        $data['text_price'] = $this->language->get('text_price');
        $data['text_wholesale'] = $this->language->get('text_wholesale');
        $data['text_tax'] = $this->language->get('text_tax');
        $data['text_points'] = $this->language->get('text_points');
        $data['text_compare'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_compare'), (isset($this->session->data['compare']) ? count($this->session->data['compare']) : 0));
        $data['text_sort'] = $this->language->get('text_sort');
        $data['text_limit'] = $this->language->get('text_limit');
        $data['logged'] = $this->customer->isLogged();
        $data['button_cart'] = $this->language->get('button_cart');
        $data['button_wishlist'] = $this->language->get('button_wishlist');
        $data['button_compare'] = $this->language->get('button_compare');
        $data['button_list'] = $this->language->get('button_list');
        $data['button_grid'] = $this->language->get('button_grid');
        $data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');

        $data['compare'] = $this->url->link('product/compare');

        $data['products'] = array();

        $filter_data = array(
            'sort'  => $sort,
            'order' => $order,
            'start' => ($page - 1) * 20,
            'limit' => $limit
        );


        $product_total = 20;

        $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductLatestS($filter_data);

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            if ($result['image']) {
                $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_width'), $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_height'));
            } else {
                $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('placeholder.png', $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_width'), $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_height'));
            }

            if ($this->customer->isLogged() || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
                $wholesale = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['wholesale'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
            } else {
                $price = false;
                $wholesale = false;
            }

            if ((float)$result['special']) {
                $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
            } else {
                $special = false;
            }

            if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
                $tax = $this->currency->format((float)$result['special'] ? $result['special'] : $result['price'], $this->session->data['currency']);
            } else {
                $tax = false;
            }

            if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                $rating = (int)$result['rating'];
            } else {
                $rating = false;
            }

            $data['products'][] = array(
                'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                'thumb'       => $image,
                'upc'       => $result['upc'],
                'name'        => $result['name'],
                'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_description_length')) . '..',
                'price'       => $price,
                'wholesale'   => $wholesale,
                'special'     => $special,
                'tax'         => $tax,
                'minimum'     => $result['minimum'] > 0 ? $result['minimum'] : 1,
                'rating'      => $result['rating'],
                'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url)
            );
        }

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
        }

        $data['sorts'] = array();

        $data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_default'),
            'value' => 'p.date_added-DESC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/latest', 'sort=p.date_added&order=DESC' . $url)
        );

        $data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_name_asc'),
            'value' => 'pd.name-ASC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/latest', 'sort=pd.name&order=ASC' . $url)
        );

        $data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_name_desc'),
            'value' => 'pd.name-DESC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/latest', 'sort=pd.name&order=DESC' . $url)
        );

        $data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_price_asc'),
            'value' => 'p.price-ASC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/latest', 'sort=p.price&order=ASC' . $url)
        );

        $data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_price_desc'),
            'value' => 'p.price-DESC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/latest', 'sort=p.price&order=DESC' . $url)
        );

        if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_rating_desc'),
                'value' => 'rating-DESC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/latest', 'sort=rating&order=DESC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_rating_asc'),
                'value' => 'rating-ASC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/latest', 'sort=rating&order=ASC' . $url)
            );
        }

        $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_model_asc'),
                'value' => 'p.model-ASC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/latest', 'sort=p.model&order=ASC' . $url)
        );

        $data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_model_desc'),
            'value' => 'p.model-DESC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/latest', 'sort=p.model&order=DESC' . $url)
        );

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        $data['limits'] = array();

        $limits = array_unique(array($this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_limit'), 20));

        sort($limits);

        foreach($limits as $value) {
            $data['limits'][] = array(
                'text'  => $value,
                'value' => $value,
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/latest', $url . '&limit=' . $value)
            );
        }

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
        }

        $pagination = new Pagination();
        $pagination->total = $product_total;
        $pagination->page = $page;
        $pagination->limit = $limit;
        $pagination->url = $this->url->link('product/latest', $url . '&page={page}');

        $data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();

        $data['results'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_pagination'), ($product_total) ? (($page - 1)) + 1 : 0, ((($page - 1)) > ($product_total - $limit)) ? $product_total : ((($page - 1) * $limit) + $limit), $product_total, ceil($product_total / $limit));

        // http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html
        if ($page == 1) {
            $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/latest', '', true), 'canonical');
        } elseif ($page == 2) {
            $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/latest', '', true), 'prev');
        } else {
            $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/latest', 'page='. ($page - 1), true), 'prev');
        }

        if ($limit && ceil($product_total / $limit) > $page) {
            $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/latest', 'page='. ($page + 1), true), 'next');
        }

        $data['sort'] = $sort;
        $data['order'] = $order;
        $data['limit'] = $limit;

        $data['continue'] = $this->url->link('common/home');

        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
        $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
        $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/latest', $data));
    }
}
```

In

> model-catalog-product-product.php file I made function getProductLatestS($data = array())

```
public function getProductLatestS($data = array()) {
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT p.product_id FROM  oc_product p LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) WHERE p.status = '1' AND p.stock_status_id = '7' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '0' GROUP BY p.product_id";

        $sort_data = array(
            'pd.name',
            'p.model',
            'p.date_available',
            'p.date_added',
            'p.price',
            'rating',
            'p.sort_order'
        );

        if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
            if ($data['sort'] == 'pd.name' || $data['sort'] == 'p.model') {
                $sql .= " ORDER BY LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")";
            } else {
                $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];
            }
        } else {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY p.date_added";
        }

        if (isset($data['order']) && ($data['order'] == 'DESC')) {
            $sql .= " DESC, LCASE(pd.name) DESC";
        } else {
            $sql .= " ASC, LCASE(pd.name) ASC";
        }

        if (isset($data['start']) || isset($data['limit'])) {
            if ($data['start'] < 0) {
                $data['start'] = 0;
            }

            if ($data['limit'] < 1) {
                $data['limit'] = 20;
            }

            $sql .= " LIMIT " . (int)$data['start'] . "," . (int)$data['limit'];
        }

        $product_data = array();

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
            $product_data[$result['product_id']] = $this->getProduct($result['product_id']);
        }

        return $product_data;
    }
```

My question is how do I make other sorting to work properly as well (sort by two parameters, with `date added` being always the first parameter)? Any suggestion is welcome, as I do not know what I am doing wrong here. Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized what was wrong with my code.
The problem was in my query in  `getProductLatestS($data = array())` function. I didn't define time interval. Say, if you want to get only products added in last 10 days, you need to define time interval like I finally did in my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT p.product_id FROM  oc_product p LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) WHERE p.status = '1' AND p.stock_status_id = '7' AND p.date_added BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) AND NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '0' ";
```

I hope this helps someone. Cheers.